# FFMPEG: Multicast packets incoming, but input stream does not open

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, udp, video-processing, multicast

I have a weird problem with ffmpeg and I was wondering if someone might know what's going on.

We have transcoding clusters outputting video to a multicast network. In some computers of the same network, I'm able to open these streams with a command like:

`ffplay -i "udp://239.{mutlticast address}:10001?localaddr={Local adapter IP which receives packets}" -nodisp -loglevel trace`

But in other computers it does not work. Particularly in a server running Centos 7 I just get:

```
[NULL @ 0x7fc9a4000920] Opening 'udp://239.xxx.xxx.xxx:10001?localaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' for reading
[udp @ 0x7fc9a40012a0] No default whitelist set 
[udp @ 0x7fc9a40012a0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

I was thinking it might be a network problem. I started Wireshark to see if the packets were coming in and the thing is, they are! As soon as I start FFMpeg/FFplay, the MPEG TS packets start coming in, but still FFMpeg won't open the stream:

```
1067 1.897872161 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 51718  Destination port: scp-config
1068 1.898576050 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 40892  Destination port: documentum-s[Malformed Packet]
1069 1.900472740 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 37505  Destination port: documentum
1070 1.901850051 192.168.194.92 -> PTS 30268.882311111 MPEG TS 1358 video-stream
1071 1.903688205 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1072 1.905842200 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 51718  Destination port: scp-config
1073 1.906249539 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1074 1.909831587 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 51718  Destination port: scp-config
1075 1.911357251 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1076 1.912000106 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1077 1.913819520 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1078 1.917778444 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 Source port: 37505  Destination port: documentum
1079 1.917802429 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
1080 1.920473981 192.168.194.92 -> 239.193.2.221 MPEG TS 1358 NULL packet
```

Anyone have any idea what can I do to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using the same version of ffmpeg on non-working computers?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but newer, upgrading was the first thing I tried.